# Sitecore Meta tags

Tags: sitecore

Is there a way to have meta-tags for sitecore items, where admin can define meta keywords, meta descriptions.

I was referring to the following document,

[Sitecore SEO user guide](http://www.codehousegroup.com/~/media/Files/pdf/Guides/sitecore-seo-guide.ashx)

SEO toolkit does not do it. How can I get this functionality?

Also, I had a look at nicam demo project, it has this meta tagging infrastructure. Where can I find something like "Nicam meta tags module"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two existing [Sitecore Marketplace](http://marketplace.sitecore.net) modules that do this:
[Metatag Manager](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/MetaTag_Manager.aspx) and [Meta-tags](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Meta-Tags.aspx).

Otherwise you could create your own by adding the metatag fields to your templates and outputting them (using either a rendering or a sublayout).

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post http://andyuzick.arke.com/2013/03/the-heart-of-meta.html

This a about the meta tag manager shared source project available at the Sitecore Marketplace. It allows many types to be manged by content owners, including the ability to add dynamic tags with no coding. The full documentation is here http://marketplace.sitecore.net/services/~/media/Marketplace/Modules/M/MetaTag%20Manager/Documents/ArkeSharedSourceMetatags1.ashx.